# Trouble connecting to mysql in NodeJs on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, node.js, econnrefused

I have tried to connect NodeJS to mysql on Windows 10, but continuously failed to.
The following is the code, which from https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_create_db.asp

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
});
```

and the following is the error message when I run code.

```
  if(err) throw err;
          ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1134:16)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\tete6\NodeJS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\tete6\NodeJS\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\tete6\NodeJS\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tete6\NodeJS\demo_db_connection.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}
```

To solve this error, I tried ...

1. change "localhost" -> "127.0.0.1", but failed.
2. add "port: 3306", but failed.
3. check if the port is available to be connected, and I found that it's never my port, fireWall problem.
   My xampp's mysql works well.
4. Even mongoDB module triggers this same error message.

I gleaned some info that this **econnrefused** error message is mainly the problem of NodeJS, not of sql module.

Is anyone to show me silver shining from this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you started your XAMPP Server?

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 -- this error came, when you not started your XAMPP server.

At the first you should right [install mysql into windows 10](https://www.onlinetutorialspoint.com/mysql/install-mysql-on-windows-10-step-by-step.html)

and see this video link [how to connect to mysql with node js](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EN6Dx22cPRI)